# return the column where a particular row has a null value in python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, missing-data

How do I return the column in a DataFrame where a *particular* row has a missing value (because I will later want to loop through these rows)?
For example when working with this

```
x=[[1,2,3],[5,np.NaN,4]]
df=pd.DataFrame(x)
```

I want the column where the second row has a `NaN` I did this and it worked, but there must be a more elegant way?

```
df.iloc[:,np.where(df.iloc[1,:].isnull())[0]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You can check [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).